# Question the convergence of the following:

Tags: functional-analysis

Question the convergence of the following:

1. The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $l_1$, 
   where $x_n=(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n},...,\frac{1}{2^n},0,0,...)$
   (here the first $n$-places have the value $\frac{1}{2^n}$)
2. The sequence  $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $l_2$, 
   where $x_n=(n\sin\frac{1}{n},n\sin\frac{1}{n},...,n\sin\frac{1}{n},0,0,...)$
   (here the first $n$-places have the value $n\sin\frac{1}{n}$)
3. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ in $l_2$ where $x_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2},...,\frac{1}{n^n},0,...)$

First off, I must say, this does seem a little ambiguous. But I have this information from class, which might help me, and others as to what is questioned here. I must do this type of question as it is on the exam.

I have that $x_n\to^{l_r}x$ (converges to $x$ in $l_r$) if
$\|x_n-x\|_{l_r} \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$, meaning that if $x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2,x_n^3...)$ and $x = (x^1,x^2,....)$ then 
$$(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_n^k-x^k|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}}\to^{n\to \infty} 0.$$

So I gather that I have to find an $x \in l_1$(in the first example) such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_n^k-x^k| \to^{n\to \infty} 0 \iff\lim_{n\to \infty}|x_n^k-x^k|=0$$

I really need help with this. Much appreciation. For the first one I would think that $(0,0,0,...) \in l_1$ and also $\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{1}{2^n}|=0.$

Comment: Hint: first prove that if $x_n \to x$ in $l_p$ then $x_n \to x$ pointwise also - use the fact that $|x_n(i) - x(i)| \le \lVert x_n - x \rVert_p$.  This will give candidate limits for the sequences in cases 1 and 2 (though in case 2 the candidate will not even be in $l_2$ so there can be no limit), and in case 3 it will immediately show there can be no limit by considering the first element.

Comment: Please can you give me a complete answer if it not too much of a problem? I am very thin on time and have three more series I have to figure out, which are like the third one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\Vert x_{n}\Vert_{1}=n\frac{1}{2^{n}}\rightarrow0$. Therefore, $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ in $l_1$.
2. Note that $n\sin\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow1$. Therefore, $x_{n}\rightarrow e=(1,1,\ldots)$ pointwise. Since $\Vert e\Vert_{2}=\infty$, what can you conclude?
3. If $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$ is convergent, then so too is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$. But we know this not to be the case.

Comment: #3 is asking whether the *series* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges in $l_2$ - so you can conclude nothing just from the fact $x_n \to 0$ in $l_2$.

Comment: I am confused about #3 the most, and it is the one i need to know the most.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler can you provide an answer for #3?

Comment: If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converged in $l_2$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n(1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ would have to be a convergent series - which it isn't.  Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ diverges in $l_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it might be this, but I wasnt sure 100 percent. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: Oh shoot, I misread the question. I thought it was about the convergence of $x_n=(1/n,1/n^2,\ldots,1/n^n,0,0\ldots)$.